# MS Graph API: Create an all day event, but set the event status to free

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In EWS, we can set an event status to free with the property: LegacyFreeBusyStatus

```
appointment.LegacyFreeBusyStatus = 0;
```

Wondering if MS Graph API can do the same thing. I've been looking through all the event properties, but cannot find any.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) is `showAs` with possible values `free`, `tentative`, `busy`, `oof`, `workingElsewhere`, `unknown`.

```
var @event = new Event
{
    ...
    ShowAs = FreeBusyStatus.Free,
    ...
}
```